# how to show length special parent element in data-attribute by jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm working on bootstrap4 and i want pass length a.part elements to modal

```
<div class="">
     <a href="#" class="part">sec1</a>
     <a href="#" class="part">sec2</a>
     <a href="#" class="part">sec3</a>
     <a href="#" class="part">sec4</a>
     <a href="#">another</a>

        <p class="text-center pt-3"><i class="icon info series_errors_but" data-partcount="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#series_link_error"></i></p>

</div>


<div class="">
         <a href="#" class="part">sec1</a>
         <a href="#" class="part">sec2</a>
         <a href="#" class="part">sec3</a>
         <a href="#">another</a>

            <p class="text-center pt-3"><i class="icon info series_errors_but" data-partcount="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#series_link_error"></i></p>

    </div>
```

this code exist multiple time in page, now i need show length of a.part tags in data-partcount attr. 
for example in first loop show 4 in data-partcount and in second loop show 3. 
a.part in another section have another count
please help me tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$('div').each(function(){
  $(this).find('i').attr('data-partcount', $(this).find('.part').length);
});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn0dfb1m/